# Is there a hook that runs on application start up?

Tags: react-native, expo

I was wondering if there is a library that contains a hook that runs on application open, or if there is a way to run functions when the app opens up (only in that instance without using any timed function)

Comment: you can do that in `componentDidMount()` in your entry file (App.js) or you can use a `useEffect` if its a function based component.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using functional components and hooks in your code, this hook below should help:

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { AppState } from "react-native";

interface UseAppStateHookProps {
  onAppEnterForeground: () => void;
}

export const useAppState = ({ onAppEnterForeground }: UseAppStateHookProps) => {
  const appState = useRef(AppState.currentState);

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = AppState.addEventListener(
      "change",
      _handleAppStateChange
    );
    return () => {
      subscription.remove();
    };
  }, []);

  const _handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
    if (
      appState.current.match(/inactive|background/) &&
      nextAppState === "active"
    ) {
      onAppEnterForeground();
    }

    appState.current = nextAppState;
  };

  return { appState };
};
```

Then in the functional component where you want to implement the hook, add the following:

```
  const appState = useAppState({
    onAppEnterForeground: () => {
      // your code here
    },
  });
```

Note: this is based on React Native's documentation on [AppState](https://reactnative.dev/docs/appstate).

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you an example:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const Player = props => {
const [playerList, setPlayer] = useState([ ])

useEffect(() => {
fetch('URL')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(fetchedPlayers => setPlayer(fetchedPlayers))
}, [ ])
}
```

We pass an empty array as the second argument. This will tell React to call the first `useEffect()` function only when it is rendered for the first time, just like we did with `componentDidMount()`.

Comment: I understand this approach, yet I need to run the function EVERY time the app opens. Without using any timed function, id rather update my app's data every time the user opens it up.

Comment: If you use useEffect in your App.js as with a Splash Screen, the data will be updated every time the user opens the application

Comment: Yeah, that definitely worked!! I also starting using useEffect in the main screen in order to update the data (this is because my app requires registration and it's unnecessary to load info before it logs).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is no such library.